# How to configure nginx in ec2 (Ubuntu 18.04) with Domain Name in AWS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, express, nginx, dns, amazon-route53

I have a domain name "domain_name.net" in a hosted zone in AWS Route 53.
I set the following records in Route 53:

Record# Name               Type     Value

1. domain_name.net.     A       [Elastic IPv4 Address]
2. domain_name.net.     NS      [Default 4 NS]
3. domain_name.net.     SOA     [Default SOA provided by AWS]
4. www.domain_name.net. A       [Elastic IPv4 Address]

(Note: the dots at the end are added by aws)

In Ubuntu, there is an app I'd like to have in reverse proxy. 
The location of the app is `http://127.0.0.1:API_PORT`

So I setup my server object like this in my config file located at 
*/etc/nginx/sites-available*:

```
server {
    listen 80;

    server_name domain_name.net www.domain_name.net;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:API_PORT;
     }
}
```

I have already linked the file to the sites-enabled by running

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/config_file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

I also tested it using

```
sudo nginx -t
```

with the result

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

and I also reloaded the nginx with

```
sudo /etc/init.d/nginx reload
```

and it gives me the following result

```
[ ok ] Reloading nginx configuration (via systemctl): nginx.service.
```

Yet, I can only access to my site via the public DNS and the Elastic IP but not the `www.domain_name.net` which I wanted to access from. Is there anything wrong here? Please tell me, thanks!

Comment: It seems like it's not using your `nginx conf`, instead using `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`. Define your server name and proxy pass there to see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: OR try  importing the conf in your `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`  using `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.*; `

Comment: Sorry for my previous wrong comments. For the first method you suggested I added a server object in the http object but the nginx -t gives me `nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "domain_name.net" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: [warn] conflicting server name "www.domain_name.net" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful`